# use nodejs v8 isolate in another native thread

Tags: javascript, node.js, v8

I needed to execute some Javascript code in another thread with the same isolate.

So I created another global-context with v8-isolate in Nodejs, and api: SetSecurityToken was also called. Then I use the same isolate and new context in another native thread.

But the native thread was blocked after I call "v8::Locker locker(isolate_)".

Maybe the isolate was locked by Nodejs thread?

Comment: You may be interested to learn that https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html exists.

Comment: I need to use the same isolate, but the worker_threads provide multi isolates. sad.

Comment: What is an "isolate" in this context? Because that sounds like something's getting lost in translation.

Comment: Using the same v8 isolate provided by Nodejs in another native thread. I created another thread in 'addon.node' and create a new context for this isolate. But I after I called v8::Locker locker(isolate_), my native thread was blocked